# How to open two windows on startup, one with mailbox, one with specific calendar selected?

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

When opening Outlook 2016, how can I to open two windows on startup, one with a mail, one with specific calendars selected?

Calendars are shared. I found a code that opens two windows, but how can I set up the window with a specific calendar selected.

I researched on internet, couldn't find anything.

```vb
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim xCalendar As Folder
    Dim xInbox As Folder
    Dim xExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim xWidth, xHeight As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    xWidth = Int(GetSystemMetrics32(0) / 4) + 60
    xHeight = GetSystemMetrics32(1)
    Set xInbox = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    xInbox.Display
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = xInbox
    Set xExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    With xExplorer
        .WindowState = olNormalWindow
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Height = xHeight
        .Width = xWidth
    End With
    Set xCalendar = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    xCalendar.Display
    Set xExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    With xExplorer
        .WindowState = olNormalWindow
        .Top = 0
        .Left = xWidth
        .Height = xHeight
        .Width = xWidth
    End With
    Set xExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    With xExplorer
        .WindowState = olNormalWindow
        .Top = 0
        .Left = xWidth * 2
        .Height = xHeight
        .Width = xWidth
    End With
    Set xExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    With xExplorer
        .WindowState = olNormalWindow
        .Top = 0
        .Left = xWidth * 3
        .Height = xHeight
        .Width = xWidth
    End With
End Sub
```

I expect this: Click to open Outlook, two windows open, one regular mail, and one with a specific calendar selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for. To use a custom group name, just set accordingly this line:

```
Set objGroup = .Item("group name")
```

Here the full code:

```
Dim WithEvents objPane As NavigationPane

'This goes on ThisOutlookSession
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane

End Sub

Private Sub objPane_ModuleSwitch(ByVal CurrentModule As NavigationModule)

    Dim objPane As NavigationPane
    Dim objModule As CalendarModule
    Dim objGroup As NavigationGroup
    Dim objNavFolder As NavigationFolder
    Dim objCalendar As Folder
    Dim objFolder As Folder

    Dim i As Integer

    If CurrentModule.NavigationModuleType = olModuleCalendar Then
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    DoEvents

    Set objCalendar = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set objPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
    Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)

    With objModule.NavigationGroups
        Set objGroup = .GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olMyFoldersGroup)

    ' To use a different group
        Set objGroup = .Item("group name")
    End With

    For i = 1 To objGroup.NavigationFolders.Count
        Set objNavFolder = objGroup.NavigationFolders.Item(i)
        Select Case i

        ' Enter the calendar index numbers you want to open
            Case 1, 3, 4
                objNavFolder.IsSelected = True

        ' Set to True to open side by side
                objNavFolder.IsSideBySide = False
            Case Else
                objNavFolder.IsSelected = False
        End Select
    Next

' set the view here

    End If

    Set objPane = Nothing
    Set objModule = Nothing
    Set objGroup = Nothing
    Set objNavFolder = Nothing
    Set objCalendar = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for helping. I've tried this code, now I get this message  when I open outlook: "Run-time error '-2079195127 (841200009)': Property cannot be set when it's parent module is not the active module.

Comment: You're welcome. That's very strange, on my Outlook (2016) it was working. If you try executing the code with F8 it works?

Comment: Maybe I need to write something in "module" on the left side?

Comment: No, I don't think so. In which line the program get stuck?

Comment: objNavFolder.IsSideBySide = True

Comment: Ok, I've updated the code. This should work with little edit based on what you need.